# Integration and fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need some help with the following integration/use of fundamental theorem of calculus:

$\displaystyle x(t) =  \int_{0}^{t} \exp (-2s)a(s) \ ds$, where

$a(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       -1 & : t \in [0,1]\\
       1& : t \in (1, \infty)
     \end{array}
   \right.$

How should I simplify the integral?

Comment: first integrate  inner part  and show us what you get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle  \exp \left \{-\int\limits_{0}^{s} 2 \ du\right \}=e^{-2s}, $ then
$$x(t)=\int\limits_{0}^{t}{e^{-2s}a(s) \ ds}=\begin{cases} -\int\limits_{0}^{t}{e^{-2s} \ ds}: &  t \in [0,1]\\ 
-\int\limits_{0}^{1}{e^{-2s} \ ds}+\int\limits_{1}^{t}{e^{-2s} \ ds}: &  t \in (1, \infty)
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Show that left and right limits at $t=1$ are equal: $$\lim\limits_{t\to{1-0}}x(t)=\lim\limits_{t\to{1+0}}x(t)=-\int\limits_{0}^{1}{e^{-2s} \ ds}=\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2e^2}$$

Comment: Why would $x$ not be continuous at $t=1$?

Answer (score 4):

Compute. If $0\le t\le 1$, we want
$$\int_0^t -e^{-2s}\,ds.$$
For $t\gt 1$, we want
$$\int_0^1 -e^{-2s}\,ds +\int_1^t e^{-2s}\,ds.$$
The integration is straightforward.